# Navigation Drop Down - Icon Changes When Active

Tags: magento-1.9, css, navigation, js-css

I have a drop-down navigation for my site - think Prada.com; users click on a little icon at the top and the entire navigation is revealed. This works perfectly, however I can't quite get the icon to work well.

Currently, when users click the icon changes from a 'menu' icon to a 'X' icon. Which is perfect, however when users start clicking somewhere within the navigation (either on a category or into empty space) the 'X' icon changes back to the menu icon. The 'X' icon should be present the entire time that the navigation is open, then once it's closed change back to a menu icon. Hopefully that makes sense. Prada is a perfect example of how it's done, seamlessly.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<a class="skip-link skip-nav skip-active" href="#header-nav">

<span class="icon"></span>
<span class="label"></span>
</a>

</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.skip-link .icon {
display: inline-block;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.skip-nav .icon, {
background-image: url("../images/icon_sprite.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
float: right;
margin-top: 8px;
}


.skip-nav {
float: right;
}

.skip-nav:not(.skip-active):hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

.skip-nav:not(.skip-active):hover .icon {
background-position: -46px 4px;
}

.skip-nav .label {
display: inline;
}

.skip-nav .icon {
}

.skip-nav:focus .icon {
background-image: url(../images/icon_sprite3.png);
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Could you share your url if you have it running live?

Comment: Unfortunately this is all on my local host.

Comment: I see, then please add screenshots.